# Can't install mdfreader version 3 due to numpy NameError in pip

Tags: python, numpy, pip, installation

I want to update mdfreader but when using the pip upgrade command I receive an error: NameError: name numpy is not defined

I have updated pip and setuptools to the latest versions and the error did not change.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-85wfmgif\mdfreader\setup.py", line 111, in <module>
entry_points = entry_points, ext_modules=ext_modules, include_dirs= 
[numpy.get_include<>])
NameError:name `numpy` is not defined

during handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-85wfmgif\mdfreader\setup.py", line 120, in <module>
entry_points = entry_points, ext_modules=ext_modules, include_dirs= 
[numpy.get_include<>])
NameError:name `numpy` is not defined
   ---------------------------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-85wfmgif\mdfreader\
```

I found a similar problem where someone had used:
    import numpy as np

and then tried to call numpy with it's full name.  I assume if that was the problem then no one would be able to install the latest version

I went to the file path but the file wasn't there I guess it just gets deleted as it's in temp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mdfreader [doesn't import numpy if Cython is not available](https://github.com/ratal/mdfreader/blob/bfde2de91eff81a3ba75430eb37a5107b5dc6486/setup.py#L10). Try

```
pip install cython
```

This is a bug in their `setup.py` and it's already [reported](https://github.com/ratal/mdfreader/issues/158).

Comment: do you mean pip install cython?  I already had numpy but the error log you linked said you need cython for the setup to work.  I installed cython and then mfdreader installed.

Comment: Yep, fixed. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [asammdf](https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf)? Disclaimer: I'm the main developer of this package